# How to convert serde_json::error::Error to reqwest::error::Error?

Tags: rust

reqwest v0.9 has serde v1.0 as a dependency and as a result implements [converting serde_json errors into reqwest error](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/blob/0.9.x/src/error.rs#L449-L454).

In my code, I am doing some deserialization using serde_json instead of using `.json()` method that comes with reqwest.

```rust
// reqwest = "0.9"
// serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
// serde_json = "1.0"

pub fn get_meta(client: &reqwest::Client) -> Result<Meta, reqwest::Error> {
    let mut resp = client
        .get("http://localhost:8080/requests/playlist.json")
        .send()?;

    let data: Value = serde_json::from_str(&resp.text()?).unwrap();
    let data = data["children"][0]["children"].clone();
    let metas: Vec<Meta> = serde_json::from_value(data).unwrap();
    let meta: Meta = metas.last().expect("nothing is playing").clone();
    Ok(meta)
}
```

Currently, I am trying to return serde_json errors as reqwest errors. Changing `let metas: Vec<Meta> = serde_json::from_value(data).unwrap();` to `let metas: Vec<Meta> = serde_json::from_value(data)?;` fails with the following error:

```
 the trait `std::convert::From<serde_json::error::Error>` is not implemented for `reqwest::error::Error`
```

Is it possible to convert `serde_json::error::Error` to `reqwest::error::Error` by wrapping it inside `Kind::Json` error enum of reqwest, or do I have to make a custom error enum that encompasses both as mentioned in this [article](https://blog.burntsushi.net/rust-error-handling/)?

Comment: The `reqwest::Error` type is the internal error type of the `reqwest` crate. It does not expose any public constructors, or `From` implementations for public types; instances can only be constructed from within the `reqwest` crate. So the short answer is: no, you can't convert any other type into `reqwest::Error`, and need to use some other error type instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't construct [`reqwest::Error`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.9.24/reqwest/struct.Error.html) value yourself because it:

- has non-public fields
- does not expose public constructors
- does not have `From` implementations for public types

Fortunately both `reqwest::Error` and `serde_json::error::Error` implement `std::error::Error` trait. Following the recommendation from the blog post you linked, the `anyhow` crate is very helpful here:

```
// reqwest = "0.9"
// serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
// serde_json = "1.0"
// anyhow = "1.0"

pub fn get_meta(client: &reqwest::Client) -> Result<Meta, anyhow::Error> {
    let mut resp = client
        .get("http://localhost:8080/requests/playlist.json")
        .send()?;

    let data: Value = serde_json::from_str(&resp.text()?).unwrap();
    let data = data["children"][0]["children"].clone();
    let metas: Vec<Meta> = serde_json::from_value(data).unwrap();
    let meta: Meta = metas.last().expect("nothing is playing").clone();
    Ok(meta)
}
```